# Jasper Reports in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I have assigned to use jasperserver reports in a rails application.
There is a plugin for jasperserver to use in Ruby application.
https://github.com/gunark/jasperserver-client
I want to know whether this plugin can use in my rails 3 version of application.
I've checked in railsplugin.org .But it shows "no result found".
I'l be please if u people gave me any help link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://github.com/gunark/jasperserver-client/wiki), the author recommends you install it as a gem & not as a plugin.  They go on to give an example of how to use the gem in a rails project on [this wiki page](https://github.com/gunark/jasperserver-client/wiki/RailsUsageExamples).

I haven't used this, but your compatibility issues probably won't be with rails. *Maybe* the ruby version or soap4r version - but there don't seem to be any rails dependencies here.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe use this simple ruby script for this => http://www.redrails.com.br/2013/03/07/ruby-client-para-rest-api-do-jasper-report-server/